# 당신의 이면에 관한 이야기입니다

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, conversation

What does this sentence mean? I am stuck with 당신의 이면 part. If it is translated as "if it is a story about you" then why don't we why it as "당신에 관한 이야기입니다"?

당신의 이면에 관한 이야기입니다.

This sentence is from [the comic here](https://comic.naver.com/bestChallenge/detail.nhn?titleId=706060&no=2) (fifth picture from the top).

Comment: Just because you see a 면, doesn't mean it's an "if".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **이면** : a) 드러나지 않는 내부의 속사정 not well-known thing.

이 소설은 권력의 이면을 그리고 있다. This novel describes
  dark side of a power.

성공의 이면에는 고뇌가 있다. Different side of success contains pains.

b) 물체의 속이나 안 inside of a thing = 내면

c) back of a thing

이면지를 활용 usage of a back side of a printed paper.

@When I find examples, the word 이면 means negative or neutral

neutral : 잘 관찰해 보면 그 사람들의 행동의 이면에 숨겨져 있는 것을 알 수 있다. When we observes carefully human's behavior, we can know charateristic.

So I have a doubt that there is a positive. For instance, 그의 무자비한 성격의 이면은 가족을 보호하려는 마음이다. His pitiless character is related to his care to his family. I can not find the sentence of this type.

Comment: So would '당신의 이면에 관한 이야기입니다' mean 'it's a story about your dark side'?

Comment: Yes. When we read the comic, the sentence means dark side